# appcelerator: uuidgen command not found

Tags: appcelerator

I am using Appcelerator Studio with a trial account. My project is not running on the device as I need a GUID for my app. Following Appcelerator's support, I am running "uuidgen" in order to get a GUID. However, I get the "uuidgen: command not found" error.

Is there anything I need to set up on Appcelerator Studio before I can run this command?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`uuidgen` is not a command from Appcelerator.

In mac, it's a default utility. But you don't get this in Windows OS.

I think you can simply generate online - https://www.uuidgenerator.net

I believe you wanted to use the generated uuid in the manifest file/tiapp.xml file.